# Why is a gratuitous ARP sent out after VM migration?

Tags: virtual-machine, migration, xen

Is it because the MAC address of the VM changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the MAC address stays the same, the *location* may change, and the VM might be connected to a different switch; the system needs to make traffic go to the new location instead of disappearing at the old one.

Comment: That makes sense. Does the MAC address remain the same or does it change?

Comment: It should remain the same -- when you're migrating a live VM, its hardware is supposed to stay the same. Changing the address from outside would introduce unnecessary complications.